# Need to find the number of times PLSQL function gets executed

Tags: oracle, plsql

There is a requirement from client side that after function get executed more than 2 times then its output should be concatinated with some string and this function is inside a package .

for example...
function get called 7 times from package (its a backend job which executed automatically) and returns 'abc' but when the job runs for the 3rd time i want output 'abcde'.

Comment: More than 2 times in what context?  More than twice in the same session?  More than twice since the database was started?  More than twice in all of time?  More than twice in the same SQL statement?  What about executions that occur in transactions that are rolled back?  Whatever the actual business requirement, this seems like a pretty odd way to implement a technical solution so I'd be interested in knowing what the actual business requirement is.

Comment: @JustinCave yes in the same session and no need to bother about rolled back thing.

Comment: How is "session" defined? Do users actually log in to the database individually, or is the function called from a scheduled job that will have a consistent session id? Or is there an application connection pool with "session" only defined at the application level (and thus invisible to the database)?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a separate log table and insert a row for each of function calls; then - within a function - check how many times it was invoked and return appropriate output. Something like this:

Log table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE flog
  2  (
  3     cuser   VARCHAR2 (30),
  4     sid     NUMBER
  5  );

Table created.
```

Package:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_test
  2  IS
  3     FUNCTION f_test
  4        RETURN VARCHAR2;
  5
  6     PROCEDURE p_test;
  7  END;
  8  /

Package created.
```

Package body:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_test
  2  IS
  3     FUNCTION f_test
  4        RETURN VARCHAR2
  5     IS
  6        l_cnt   NUMBER;
  7        retval  VARCHAR2 (10);
  8     BEGIN
  9        SELECT COUNT (*)
 10          INTO l_cnt
 11          FROM flog
 12         WHERE     cuser = USER
 13               AND sid = SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SID');
 14
 15        retval := CASE WHEN l_cnt <= 2 THEN 'abc' ELSE 'abc' || 'de' END;
 16        RETURN retval;
 17     END;
 18
 19     PROCEDURE p_test
 20     IS
 21     BEGIN
 22        FOR i IN 1 .. 3
 23        LOOP
 24           INSERT INTO flog (cuser, sid)
 25                VALUES (USER, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SID'));
 26
 27           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Execution #' || i || ', result = ' || f_test);
 28        END LOOP;
 29     END;
 30  END pkg_test;
 31  /

Package body created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> EXEC pkg_test.p_test;
Execution #1, result = abc
Execution #2, result = abc
Execution #3, result = abcde

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: you could also use a global temporary table, then there is no need to check the sid - since the data in that gt table is only visible within the session. It would make the code even simpler and there is no maintenance on the log table.

Comment: Good idea, @Koen!